# URL Rewrite Issue - Rule works as a redirect but not as a Rewrite

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, cdn

I have been attempting to figure out why this rule works as a redirect and not as a rewrite. It didn't occur to me try it as a redirect until several hours later and to my surprise it worked.

Could you explain why the first one works but the second one doesn't?

**Redirect**

```
<rule name="Rewrite to images.cdn.com" enabled="true">
<match url="^images/(.+)$" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://images.cdn.com/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

**Rewrite**

```
<rule name="Rewrite to images.cdn.com" enabled="true">
<match url="^images/(.+)$" />
<action type="Rewrite" url="http://images.cdn.com/{R:1}"/>
</rule>
```

**Failed Request Log information**
Both the Substitution and rewrite are identical which means it should work since you can copy that url into your browser and it will work.

```
<EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-6C00-0080000000F8}</Data>
  <Data Name="Substitution">http://39e403d64323deb9e704-7fcaccb4b31037dfec2feb2a157f55bc.r52.cf1.rackcdn.com/images/updateprogress.gif</Data>
  <Data Name="RewriteURL">http://39e403d64323deb9e704-7fcaccb4b31037dfec2feb2a157f55bc.r52.cf1.rackcdn.com/images/updateprogress.gif</Data>
  <Data Name="AppendQueryString">false</Data>
  <Data Name="LogRewrittenURL">false</Data>
 </EventData>
```

Thank you!

ASP.NET / IIS 7.0

Comment: I have updated my answer on the following post, let me know if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14406762/1443490

Comment: Awesome! What a relief! Thank you! My mind has been mauling over this since yesterday.

Comment: Glad it helped, took me a while to figure this one out!

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found at this post: [Rewrite Subfolder to Subdomain in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14269149/699400)

Basically a module was missing and proxy settings needed to be set. Many kudos to @cheesmacfly