# IIS Rewrite Rule not behaving as expected

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to route `http://www.domain.com/some/url(.*)` (everything behind `/url`) to `http://some.other.com/some/url{R:1}` (where {R:1} becomes the contents of (.*) in the matched url.

I tried the rule below and all sorts of variations but none seem to rewrite correctly:

```
<rule name="Reverse Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^some\/url\/(.*)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://some.other.com/some/url/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: When using `Rewrite` to a different domain, you need to first install ARR or use `Redirect` instead. See if it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269149/rewrite-subfolder-to-subdomain-in-web-config/14406762#14406762

Comment: ARR is installed. I've also enabled the proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex may be the issue.
If you want to redirect everything after `some/url` then use:

```
<rule name="Reverse Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^some/url(.+)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://some.other.com/some/url/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

If you want to redirect everything after `some/url/` and keep the path, then you can use:

```
<rule name="Reverse Proxy" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^some/url/(.+)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://some.other.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

You can easily test your pattern with the IIS test pattern tool.
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/testing-rewrite-rule-patterns

**EDIT**

What I have done to test the second rule:

- Setup the `test.com` domain to redirect to my server (using the host
  file)
- Setup the rule with IIS as follow: [image: rules]

Giving the following configuration in the `web.config` file:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^some/url/(.+)$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://www.google.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

- Reach `http://test.com/some/url/google` with a browser:
  [image: Chrome]

It shows that the URL is rewritten using Google as destination and taking as parameter the path first requested.

Comment: I tried both your solutions, but they don't match the urls: `http://www.domain.com/some/url` or `http://www.domain.com/some/url/` or `http://www.domain.com/some/url/anything`

Comment: By "don't match" I mean that I just see the pages on `domain.com` and not `some.domain.com`...

Comment: @ReFocus I have updated my answer with a test example I have done. What if you use for test only `google.com` instead of `some.domain.com`?

Comment: If you try to put a website like `google.com` it doesn't work? Does your server have access to `some.domain.com`?

Comment: Both `domain.com` and `some.domain.com` are IIS websites on the same server. So is the webfarm...

Comment: Then not sure why it doesn't work...What if you try to rewrite to an outside website? Is `some.domain.com` available directly from your web server?

Comment: For `google.com` i get the same results: redirect works but rewrite doesn't (to make sure: `some.domain.com` also _works when redirecting_. And it's available from my server yes.

Comment: If you use (Failed Request Tracing)[http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules], can you find any interesting information?

Answer (score 1):

I had struggled on this for several days. 10-20 rewrite rule I tried and  reasons of failure are:

1. If you trying redirecting in VisualStudio(2012/2013/2015) it could not work in actual IIS hosted site as VS generates its own cert while debugging(when you specify in project properties) as well as permission issues are taken care by VS.
2. The site in IIS should have valid (no copy paste of file from thawte/verisign enabled website or even self signed generated by snk.exe) certificate; please don't assume that without valid cert you can. (self signed (also known as dev cert) in IIS 8 and 10 worked for me; difference between purchased and self signed is [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html)). The certificate should be installed as IIS can have multiple certs but each web site should use its own separate cert.
3. The site bindings should have both http(80) and https(443)
4. Now redirection syntax comes in picture; several are out there on Internet; you can get the correct regular expression easily
5. Another side of story also has to be considered that redirecting can be handle using Global.asax->Application_BeginRequest or ActionFilter in MVC 4/5.

   Doing redirection using config or programmatically can lead to different errors(`TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`, `<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />`  `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` in web.config)
6. Another gotcha I faced is redirecting from http->https is working fine but I am not able to comeback from https->http;
7. Consider your scenario(and generally should not mix) out of the available choices

   ```
   HttpRedirect::
   Request 1 (from client):    Get file.htm
   Response 1 (from server): The file is moved, please request the file newFileName.htm
   Request 2 (from client):    Get newFileName.htm
   Response 2 (from server): Here is the content of newFileName.htm

   UrlRewrite::
   Request 1 (from client):     Get file.htm
   URL Rewriting (on server):   Translate the URL file.htm to file.asp
   Web application (on server): Process the request (run any code in file.asp)
   Response 1 (from server):    Here is the content of file.htm (note that the client does not know that this is the content of file.asp)
   ```

whether you need HttpRedirect or UrlRewrite

https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/rewrite-vs-redirect-what-s-the-difference