# rewrite page from cname domain

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting, httpresponse, cname

I have two sites:
`http://blog.site.com` and `http://www.site.com`

Both sites are on different servers and different IP addresses (different hosting providers).

I would like to create rule which helps to rewrite the page

The URL will look like 
`http://www.site.com/logs/current_pages/` to the site visitor but it will really hit
`http://blog.site.com/logs/current_pages/`

Is it possible?

Please check this, it is not working

```
<rule name="cname domain">
      <match url="/logs/(.+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://blog.site.com{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: [Yes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269149/rewrite-subfolder-to-subdomain-in-web-config), it is [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248094/how-to-rewrite-url-as-subdomain-in-asp-net-without-actually-creating-a-subdomain)

Comment: sorry, there was a typo. It is not working

Comment: Ok, so you are probably missing a `/` in: `url="http://blog.site.com{R:0}"`. It should be `url="http://blog.site.com/{R:0}"`

Comment: ever this is not working

Comment: As a test can you change `type="Rewrite"` to `type="Redirect"` and see if it goes where it should?

Comment: yes redirect is working fine but not rewrite

Comment: Do you have the [Application Request Routing module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing) installed and setup with the proxy mode enabled?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30993/discussion-between-abhi-shah-and-cheesemacfly)